# dynamic queries to find birthdays liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay-6, hibernate-criteria

i m using liferay 6.2 ga2 and either want to use dynamic queries or custom sql queries to fetch data from table and here is the SQL which i have written to fetch data based on condition

```html
SELECT Emp_Name, Emp_Department, DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y'), '-', SUBSTRING(Emp_DOB,4,2), '-', SUBSTRING(Emp_DOB,1,2)), '%d-%b') as Emp_DOB
FROM tbl_mldobtest
WHERE Emp_DOB IN (
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%d-%m'),
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d-%m'),
    DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+INTERVAL 2 DAY,'%d-%m')
)
ORDER BY tbl_mldobtest.Emp_DOB;
```

and i want to implement same thing in dynamic queries or custom sql queries so that my dynamic queries or custom sql queries also fetch same data and below is links which i have referrred for same

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/06/liferay-dynamic-query-api.html

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/06/liferay-custom-sql-using-native-sql.html

but i m not getting solution to implement dynamic queries or even custom sql queries as below sql and can we use where condition as specified above in mysql query in custom sql queries because in all the blogs of custom sql queries liferay are passing values as parameter so  if anybody can help me for same can be great help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about if this achieveable by Dynamic Query API but you can definitely use custom-sql to achieve this.

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-custom-sql-queries

Comment: Hi,  can you please help me how to achieve this in custom-sql-queries. for custom-sql basic understanding i have referred below link                                                                             http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/06/liferay-custom-sql-using-native-sql.html